# Prove solution for Non-linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How can one prove that a non-linear PDE, let's say heat equation 
\begin{cases}
u_{t} = u_{xx} + u^2 -3, \quad x \in (0,1), \ \  t > 0 \\
u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0 \\
u(x, 0)  =g(x) 
\end{cases}
has at most one solution in $C^2([0,1] \times [0, \infty))$?

The book I am using already assumes this is true and does not go into detail on why it is so. I have tried to search for answers from the internet but with no luck

Comment: This certainly is no heat equation. It looks more like a nonlinear wave equation.

Comment: Sorry. I meant $u_t$. It should be fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Energy estimates should still work, but my previous comment included the energy for the wave equation. Here, you’ll want to let $u,v$ be two solutions and consider $$E(t) = \int^1_0 w(x,t)^2 dx$$ where $w=u-v$.

Comment: Thanks. What was your previous comment?

Comment: My previous comment is irrelevant now; it’s the same comment with the energy defined differently. The one in the above comment is correct for this equation and will give uniqueness by the standard argument (take a derivative, insert the equation, integrate by parts, use gronwall’s ineq...)

Comment: By following your steps, I arrived with $E'(t) = 2 \int_0^1(w_x(x,t))^2 dx - 2\int_0^1 (-w^3(x,t)) dx \leq 0$. Anything else?

Comment: I think you may have done something slightly wrong. There shouldn't be a $w^3$ because $w$ doesnt satisfy the same equation. I will post an answer.

Comment: I think I got the answer. Thank you

Comment: Repost of [this (closed) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3647314)

Answer (score 1):

Following from my comment, let $u,v \in C^2([0,1]\times [0,\infty))$ be two solutions to the equation, and let $w = u-v$. Then $$w_t = u_t - v_t = u_{xx} + u^3 - 3 - (v_{xx} + v^3 -3) = w_{xx} +u^3-v^3.$$ Now $u^3 - v^3 = (u-v)(u^2+uv+v^2) = w(u^2+uv+v^2)$. Now define $$E(t) = \frac 1 2\int_0^1 w(x,t)^2dx.$$ Then $$E'(t) = \int^1_0 w(x,t)w_t(x,t)dx = \int^1_0 w(w_{xx}+w(u^2+uv+v^2))dx.$$ Integrating by parts for the first term, and noting that the boundary terms disappear, gives $$E'(t) = \int^1_0 [- w_x^2 + w^2(u^2+uv+v^2)]dx. $$ Now on any fixed time interval $[0,T]$, the function $u^2+uv+v^2$ remains bounded; say $u^2+uv+v^2 \le M$. Further, the $-w_x^2$ term is non-positive, so $$E'(t) \le \int^1_0 w^2(u^2+uv+v^2)dx\le M\int^1_0 w^2 dx = ME(t).$$ Gronwall's inequality yields $$E(t) \le E(0)e^{Mt}, \,\,\,\,\ \text{ for } t \in [0,T].$$ But $E(0) = 0$ since $w(x,0) = u(x,0) -v(x,0) = g(x) - g(x) = 0$. Thus $E(t) \le 0$ and so $w^2 = 0$ on $[0,T]$, and $T$ was arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you very much!